# Independent Variable effect's change Between Two Periods

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, conditional-probability, cox-model, predictor

I used the Cox proportional-hazards model, which investigates the relationship between the time of occurrence of an event and a set of explanatory variables in the presence of censored data.
The goal of my study is to investigate the impact of the interaction between X1 and X2 (which are two strategies) on firm survival. Giving that X2 may be initiated by the firm in two times ( before X1 or after X1).

So we can say that i may have many scenarios:

X1 (0) X2(before x1) (0) X2(after x1) (0)
X1 (1) X2(before x1) (0) X2(after x1) (0)
X1 (1) X2(before x1) (1) X2(after x1) (0)
X1 (1) X2(before x1) (0) X2(after x1) (1)
X1 (1) X2(before x1) (1) X2(after x1) (1)

Ok!
So, before i tested the interaction effect, i regressed only as independent variables (X1, X2before, X2after) in order to have an idea about the direct effect of the second strategy on firm survival which is X2.

I that found that the effect of X2 is changing (X2 Before, X2 After) is this normal? if yes, how can i explain it? Thank a lot for your answers.

All respect

Table : Regression results
Controle var1   -0.454943***
Controle var1   -0.286742***
Controle var1   -0.095798***
X1               2.261359***
X2_before        0.600258***
X2_after        - 0.864314***

Obs.   33828
Pseudo R2  0.093827

Standard errors are in parenthesis
*** p<0.01, ** p<0.05, * p<0.1

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details about the nature of your study. It's not clear to me what you mean by "I regressed my independent variable in two periods." You might need to treat this as a time-varying covariate, but there isn't enough information about the time course of entering the study, making measurements, doing treatment, and follow-up to know for sure.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, ok i will added new details in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having 2 treatments that can occur at different times and different orders is tricky. Here's one example of what might be going on.

Let's say that firms who start with treatment X1 tend to wait a while before they start with treatment X2. A firm likely to fail under treatment X1 might then never survive to the point that it could start treatment X2. Firms that were already likely to survive under treatment X1 were those that lived long enough to start treatment X2. So the negative regression coefficient for "X2 after X1" might just be an example of [survivorship bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias). Only longer-lived firms would be included in that "treatment" group to start with.

This situation probably needs to be handled with treatments coded as [time-dependent covariates](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf), explicitly coding the times at which each treatment was started. Even then, you will have to think carefully about what's going on, based on your understanding of the subject matter, to make sure that you're not just examining survivorship bias in some scenarios.

Finally, don't put too much faith in the p-values, as you seem to have a very large number of cases. With a large number of cases it's easy to find "statistically significant" results that are of little practical importance. You should think about whether the low pseudo-R^2 indicates that your model isn't picking up much useful information.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation its very useful for me!

Comment: @RachidACHBAH if you think that this answers your question, please mark this answer as accepted.